# Returning Null values to access database through OleDb

Tags: c#, oledb

I have set an INSERT statement up to return values to the database if the textbox is empty however it is still failing on the insert.

I am experiencing 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

where am i going wrong?

my fields in access are not set to required

```
private void NewCustomer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection();
    Conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=BoilerSvc_be.mdb";
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Contacts (Title,Initial,Surname,[Address 1],[Address 2],[Address 3],[Post Town],[Post Code],Telephone,Archived) VALUES (@Title,@FirstName,@LastName,@Address1,@Address2,@Address3,@PostTown,@PostCode,@Telephone,Archived = 0)";

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName.Text))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", title.Text);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName.Text))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", title.Text);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address1.Text))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", title.Text);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address2.Text))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", title.Text);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address3.Text))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address3", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address3", title.Text);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Postcode.Text))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", title.Text);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TownCity.Text))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostTown", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostTown", title.Text);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhnNum.Text))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", title.Text);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Titl.Text))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title.Text);
    }

    Conn.Open();
    command.Connection = Conn;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Conn.Close();

    FirstName.Text = null;
    LastName.Text = null;
    Address1.Text = null;
    Address2.Text = null;
    Address2.Text = null;
    Postcode.Text = null;
    TownCity.Text = null;
    Titl.Text = null;
    PhnNum.Text = null;
    Address3.Text = null;

    MessageBox.Show("Customer Added");
}
```

Comment: I think you should remove the "Archived = 0"  at the end. And just put 0.

Comment: Aside from anything else, I don't think `OleDbCommand` supports named parameters at all: "The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used."

Comment: 1. You have `title.Text` everywhere on your `AddWithValue` where you mean to add the specific text for that item. 2. `Archived = 0` wont work because you do not know the value of `Archived` at insert time, you need to provide a value (this is the main culprit). 3. Wrap your Connection object in a `using` statement so it is always closed. 4. Good job on parameters but please do not forget to specify the parameter type, you can chain this to `AddWithValue`. Finally parameters are position based for OleDb so the order of parameters in the query should match exactly the parameters in collection.

Comment: And **most importantly**, when asking for help and you have an error / exception please **provide the details of that exception/error** otherwise we are all guessing at what the problem could be. Those exceptions are usually very specific and contain very useful information. Things to include from your exception: 1. The type, 2) the Message property 3) the stack trace 4) any additional exception type specific info 5) the inner exception if not null and provide everything again starting with 1.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I'm not sure if this will work with an OleDb-connection but you should rewrite your code like this assuming it would accept the named parameters.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=BoilerSvc_be.mdb"))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Contacts (Title,Initial,Surname,[Address 1],[Address 2],[Address 3],[Post Town],[Post Code],Telephone,Archived) VALUES (@Title,@FirstName,@LastName,@Address1,@Address2,@Address3,@PostTown,@PostCode,@Telephone,0)";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName.Text) ? DBNull.Value : title.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName.Text) ? DBNull.Value : title.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address1.Text) ? DBNull.Value : title.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address2.Text) ? DBNull.Value : title.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address3", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address3.Text) ? DBNull.Value : title.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Postcode.Text) ? DBNull.Value : title.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostTown", string.IsNullOrEmpty(TownCity.Text) ? DBNull.Value : title.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhnNum.Text) ? DBNull.Value : title.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Titl.Text) ? DBNull.Value : title.Text);

        Conn.Open();
        command.Connection = Conn;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    FirstName.Text = null;
    LastName.Text = null;
    Address1.Text = null;
    Address2.Text = null;
    Address2.Text = null;
    Postcode.Text = null;
    TownCity.Text = null;
    Title.Text = null;
    PhnNum.Text = null;
    Address3.Text = null;

    MessageBox.Show("Customer Added");
}
```

Comment: I made 1 change, I added a `using` block around the connection which should always be done so the connection is not left open in the event of an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, for OleDb parameters you have to use question marks instead:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (var Conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=BoilerSvc_be.mdb"))
        {
            var command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Contacts (" + 
                                 "Title,   Initial,  Surname,[Address 1],[Address 2],[Address 3],[Post Town],[Post Code],Telephone,Archived)" +
                        " VALUES (    ?,         ?,        ?,          ?,          ?,          ?,          ?,          ?,        ?,       0)", Conn);
            Control[] controls = { Titl, FirstName, LastName,   Address1,   Address2,   Address3,   TownCity,   Postcode,   PhnNum };

            foreach (var control in controls)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + control.Name,
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text) ? DBNull.Value : control.Text as object);

            Conn.Open();
            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Customer Added");
                foreach (var control in controls)
                    control.Text = "";
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Customer was not Added");

        } // Conn is closed and disposed at the end of the using block
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { 
        MessageBox.Show("Exception : " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```